# add rods type element in the background behind views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my `XML` I have 4 views, three `CardView`s and one is just a relative view (which is inflated as of other `CardView`s through activity and it have id of `container` in XML below). I want to attach the rod type of element connected with each view one after another in their below in background.

[image: figure]

This is code of that rod element I want.

```
<!-- vertical rod, I want like this rod in background of these four views -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:background="@color/black"/>
```

and this the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECEAEA"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_post_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_head"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_view_category_status"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="1dp"
                        >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="12"
                            >
                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                                app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="10"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/video_detail_title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:maxLines="2"
                                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:lines="1"
                                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- this is the native ad contaainer, I will inflate this in activity -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_content2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_head"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:weightSum="12"
                        >
                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="10"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_title2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_head"

                android:id="@+id/relative_layout_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="1dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="12"
                    >
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_title3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want those rod type of element as of the picture in the background. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, is your project has ConstraintLayout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECEAEA"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_post_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:background="@color/black"/>

            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_head"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/card_view_category_status"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                        app:cardElevation="1dp"
                        >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:weightSum="12"
                            >
                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                                app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                                android:layout_weight="10"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/video_detail_title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:maxLines="2"
                                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textSize="18sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:lines="1"
                                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textSize="15sp"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- this is the native ad contaainer, I will inflate this in activity -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_content2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_head"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:weightSum="12"
                        >
                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="10"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_title2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="18sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:lines="1"
                                android:text="@string/app_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linear_layout_head"
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                app:cardElevation="1dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:weightSum="12"
                    >
                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_thumb2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="10"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_title3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/video_detail_category_title3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:lines="1"
                            android:text="@string/app_name"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                            android:textSize="15sp"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add it above scrollview make scrollview alignbottomof it

Comment: I warped with linearlayout and set orientation to vertical, will it be as a good method?

Comment: It's best for this case you want